# How to center an icon widget inside a Container with circular boundary

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I face a problem that eventually others already have a solution for.

I want to Flutter Container circle box shape, a border of size >=1 and Icon as child perfectly centered in the middle of the container.

However Flutter does all kinds of weird things which screws up the center location of the icon. Neither Aligment.center nor the Center widget helps.

I tried with Stack and position but I think this is just not the way to do it as there must be a direct way to get the icon in the Container perfectly centered and force Flutter not to change the size of the Icon or add paddings or shift the child around.

Here is a code snip

```
if (widget.selected) {
      return Container(
        width: widget.size,
        height: widget.size,
        constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: widget.size, height: widget.size),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 5),
          color: Colors.yellow,
        ),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Icon(Icons.check_circle, size: widget.size-5, color: Colors.lightGreen),
      );
    }
    else
      return Container(
        width: widget.size,
        height: widget.size,
        constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: widget.size, height: widget.size),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 5),
          color: Colors.transparent,
        ),
      );
```

[image]

I also inspected the widget tree and I find things to happen that I don't want to have there.

Comment: Did you try rapping the Icon widget with a Center widget?

Comment: I also tried that, yes, no effect.

Comment: I understand that Flutter adds padding down the widget tree of size 5, becaues of the border of size 5. But that does not explain why the icon is not centered. It also happens for other icons and fonts, so it is not a problem related to the specific icon font either.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Stack` instead of a `Column` and separate the `Icon` and the `Container`.

```
        Stack(
            children: [
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 5),
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Icon(Icons.check_circle,
                      size: 190, color: Colors.lightGreen)),
            ],
          ),
```

Comment: I think the problem is in the icon size and how Flutter handles the icons in RichText with fontSize set to iconSize. Now if fontSize > innerSize = 100 - 2*5 = 90, the RichText widget miss-aligns. Is this a bug or a feature? Your code works not because of no box constraints but because iconSize = 90 = 100-2*borderWidth.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Check the new code please.

Comment: If you wrap the whole Stack in a Container with a fixed height and width make sure the Container area is bigger or at least same as the Icon.